# How does fingerprint authentication work with iOS/Android?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm a bit confused as to how fingerprint/face authentication works with IOS and Native. I've got the following (https://github.com/niklasmerz/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio) working within my Cordova application but not sure how this ties into authenticating a user to a service.

For example:

1. Given I have backend API, how would I tell the backend that the user has now logged in? they didn't provide a username/password—only a fingerprint validation.
2. How would I be able to authenticate them against external services that require a email/password? This sort of ties into the first question.

Comment: Generally you get them to log in with their username/password the first time and store this data securely (In the keychain on iOS).  Then, when they provide a biometric authentication later you can retrieve the stored data from the keychain and send it to your backend.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use something like the following to store/retrieve username/password (https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage)?

Comment: I don't use Cordova, but yes, that looks like the sort of thing.